# Joomla 3 Change website language from framework

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

We have our site in dutch but we are opening a version in France. We decided to just have the French language when people go to the .fr version of our site and the dutch version if people go to the .nl version.

So I created an `onAfterInitialise` plugin that gets the domain and now I want to set the language to french. We created overrides for the important language strings.

But how do I change the language to fr_FR? I tried the documentation but noticed that setLanguage is deprecated now in Joomla 3?

Greetings,

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  `JLanguage::getInstance` instead of `setLanguage` as it is deprecated. To change a language of site you can use

```
$lang_code = "fr_FR";
$newLang = JLanguage::getInstance($lang_code);
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->loadLanguage($newLang);
```

This will load the french language in .fr site.

Comment: In `onAfterInitialise` this doesnt work, jText's aren't updated. But I downloaded a plugin which uses your code, but in multiple events, like `onAfterDispatch` and `onAfterRoute`. Can you shed some more light on this? Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @HansWassink Can you please let me know which plugin is that? Also for all the event details you can refer this link https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events .

Comment: The plugin is this one: https://www.yireo.com/software/joomla-extensions/language-domains . I am aware of the events, but I need to study how they did it, because calling `loadLanguage` in onAfterInitialise doesn't work :)